# Fibonacci in python receiving syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, fibonacci

I'm trying to run this fibonacci.py to get a row of numbers until 10 using dp method with this command <kbd>python fibonacci.py 10 dp all</kbd>

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib_dp(n: int) -> int:
    """
    Solves the fibonacci series using simple recursion and built
    in memoization
    Args:
        n: the nth row

    Returns:
        the addition of n-1, i + n-1, i-1
    """
    if n < 0:
        return INVALID
    if fib_table[n] != INVALID:
        return fib_table[n]
    fib_table[n] = fib_dp(n - 1) + fib_dp(n - 2)
    return fib_table[n]
```

but getting a syntax error

```
File "fibonacci.py", line 30
    def fib_dp(n: int) -> int:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This entire code as follows:

```
from enum import Enum
from functools import lru_cache
import click
import sys

STACK_LIMIT = 1000
MAX_FIB = 500
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

class FibonacciType(Enum):
    DP = 2
    RECURSIVE = 1
    ITERATIVE = 0


# fib table
fib_table = [INVALID] * MAX_FIB

# invalid value for memoization table(fib_table)
INVALID = -1



@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib_dp(n: int) -> int:
    """
    Solves the fibonacci series using simple recursion and built
    in memoization
    Args:
        n: the nth row

    Returns:
        the addition of n-1, i + n-1, i-1
    """
    if n < 0:
        return INVALID
    if fib_table[n] != INVALID:
        return fib_table[n]
    fib_table[n] = fib_dp(n - 1) + fib_dp(n - 2)
    return fib_table[n]

def fib_iter(n: int) -> int:
    if n in {0, 1}:
        return n

    x, y, curr = 0, 1, 0
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        curr = x + y
        x = y
        y = curr
    return curr


def fib_rec(n: int) -> int:
    if n < 0:
        return 0
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    return fib_rec(n - 1) + fib_rec(n - 2)


def get_entire_row(n: int, type: int, print_it: bool) -> list[int]:
    entire_row = []

    if type == 0:
        for i in range(n):
            entire_row.append(fib_iter(i))
    elif type == 1:
        for i in range(n):
            entire_row.append(fib_rec(i))
    elif type == 2:
        for i in range(MAX_FIB):
            fib_table[i] = INVALID

        fib_table[0] = 0
        fib_table[1] = 1

        for i in range(n):
            entire_row.append(fib_dp(i))

    if print_it:
        print(entire_row)
    return entire_row


def get_nth(n: int, type: int) -> None:
    if type == 0:
        print(fib_iter(n))
    elif type == 1:
        print(fib_rec(n))
    elif type == 2:
        for i in range(MAX_FIB):
            fib_table[i] = INVALID

        fib_table[0] = 0
        fib_table[1] = 1

        print(fib_dp(n))


@click.command()
@click.argument("n", type=click.IntRange(min=0, max=50000, clamp=True))
@click.option("--algo", type=click.Choice(['recursive', 'dp', 'iterative'], case_sensitive=False), default='iterative')
@click.option("--print-type", type=click.Choice(['all', 'none', 'Nth'], case_sensitive=False), default='none')
def main(n: int, algo: int, print_type: str):
    """
    Prints the string the row/ generates the row of the fibonacci series.

    Args:
        algo:
        print_type:
        n: the nth row to generate
    """
    print_it = print_type == 'all'
    t = FibonacciType.ITERATIVE
    if algo == 'recursive':
        t = FibonacciType.RECURSIVE
    elif algo == 'dp':
        t = FibonacciType.DP
    row = get_entire_row(n, t.value, print_it)

    if print_type == 'all':
        print(row)
    elif print_type == 'Nth':
        get_nth(n, t.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I don't know why it won't run

Answer (score 2):

Your Python version doesn't support type hints. Type hints were introduced in [Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/3.5.html). Run the file with a newer version. You can check the current version with `python --version`

Comment: Also, if you're on some older versions of Linux, you may already have a newer Python under the alias `python3`. For awhile, Ubuntu still mapped the name `python` to Python 2 and `python3` to a modern version of Python. I'm not sure if they're still doing that by default.